# How to create a ORACLE database in R Studio?

Tags: sql, r, database, oracle

I want to create an Oracle Database in R Studio, and then use Oracle SQL queries in R Markdown.

I have been successful in creating an SQLite Database by following steps:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)


# Create a Database
con <- dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(),
             dbname = ":memory:")

# Store the Tables in the Database
dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
         name = "actv_ts",
         value = actv_ts)

# Load the who table
dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
         name = "SP_CURRENT",
         value = SP_CURRENT)
```

But I need to create an ORACLE Database.

Comment: You will need to install Oracle database software (XE edition is free), create an instance, setup network connectivity, provision a user, etc. You can't just create create data files from an API.

Comment: At the bottom of the [Oracle XE info page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html) are links on installing Oracle XE for windows and for linux. If you're on windows, you'll need (among other things) Win10Pro (or I'm assuming Win11Pro) or better, the Home variants are not listed as supported (for many reasons, I'm sure, including Hyper-V support). (I would not try this in WSL/WSL2.)

Comment: Why do you say you must have Oracle? Is there something about SQLite that is insufficient for your needs? If so, have you considered DuckDB? It is a postgresql-variant, similar to SQLite, that is also file-based instead of server-based. There are some constraints with it (including some multi-access problems), but it is very performant, has more R-friendly data types than SQLite, and is also FOSS and well maintained.